# Whats the difference between a perfect pass and a good pass?

Tags: forza-motorsport-5

I have been racing in Forza 5 against several AI.  Frequently when I pass them up, it will say either Good Pass or Perfect Pass.    What's the difference between them?  What constitutes a perfect pass?

Answer (score 3):

A perfect pass is passing within only a couple inches of the other vehicle without touching them, good means you were farther away from them.

Comment: awesome.  I will try this tonight! Thanks :)